# Как менять url в iframe при навигации по ссылкам?

Tags: javascript, iframe

При загрузке мой сайт загружается во фрейм. Но адрес остается тот, который был у страницы при загрузке, а по навигации по сайту во фрейме url не подменяется
Пока это реализовано так

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#opt-iframe").length === 0) {
      $("body").addClass("opt-outer-body");
      $(".settings").after('<iframe id="opt-iframe"></iframe>');
      var contFrame = $("#opt-iframe")[0];
      if (contFrame) {
        $("body").css({ overflow: "hidden" });
        contFrame.addEventListener("load", function() {
          contFrame.contentWindow.document.querySelector(".settings").remove();
        });
        contFrame.src = window.top.location.href + "?" + new Date().getTime();
      }
    }
  });
```

Додумалась только до того, чтобы мне отлавливать событие по клику на любую ссылку и подменять src фрейма. Но как реализовать пока не пойму. Есть у кого-нибудь варианты как это правильно делать?

Answer (score 0):

Из соображений безопасности браузеры начинают запрещать односторонний доступ как внутрь фрейма, так и наружу. Вам необходимо организовать двустороннее взаимодействие между вашим сайтом и сайтом-обёрткой.

Пример страницы сайта-обёртки /frame-page/index.php (с помощью формы можно передавать сайту во фрейме необходимые параметры, добавив нужные инпуты):

```
<style>
    #frame {
        width: 100%;
        border: 0;
        height: 100vh;
    }
</style>
<iframe name="frame" id="frame"></iframe>
<form id="form" style="display:none;" method="post" target="frame" enctype = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
</form>
<script>
    function tractMessage(evt) {
        if (!document.origin.includes(evt.origin)) {
            return;
        }
        if (evt.data.location != undefined) {
            var adr = document.location.origin + document.target + evt.data.location.pathname + evt.data.location.search;
            window.history.replaceState(null, null, adr);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Инициализация фрейма
     * @param String origin Url нашего сайта (без слэша в конце)
     * @param String target Директория на сайте пользователя (без слэша в конце)
     * @returns {undefined}
     */
    function InitFrame(origin, target) {
        document.target = target;
        document.origin = origin;
        var page;
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener("message", tractMessage, false);
        } else {
            window.attachEvent("onmessage", tractMessage);
        }
        // сообщаем сайту внутри фрейма страницу и параметры
        page = origin + document.location.pathname.replace(target, '') + document.location.search;
        var form = document.getElementById('form');
        form.action = page;
        form.submit();
    }
    // Будем отображать сайт https://my-site.ru на странице /frame-page/
    InitFrame("https://my-site.ru", '/frame-page');
</script>
```

Ваш сайт после загрузки должен отправлять информацию об адресе страницы сайту-обёртке:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    adjustFrame();
}
function adjustFrame() {
    parent.window.postMessage({
        location: {
            host: document.location.host,
            href: document.location.href,
            pathname: document.location.pathname,
            protocol: document.location.protocol,
            search: document.location.search
        },
    }, "*");
}
```

Кроме того, необходимо организовать перенаправление на сайте-обёртке, иначе адресная строка хоть и будет меняться, но переход по ней не будет выдавать верную страницу:

```
// Перенаправление через .htaccess:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^?]*)$
RewriteRule ^frame-page/(.*)/$ /frame-page/index.php?URL=$1&%1 [L]
```

Ну, и ваш сайт, получив параметр URL, должен сделать перенаправление

Comment: спасибо за помощь, буду разбираться